# Как превратить двумерный масив в одномерный на javascript

Tags: javascript, массивы

Нужно превратить двумерный массив в одномерный. Я пытался что-то написать и даже немного приблизился к разгадке. 
Вот мой код:

```js
var arr = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
];
var arr2 = [];
for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
 console.log(`i = ${i}`);
    for(j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++){
  console.log(`j = ${j}`)
  console.log(`k = ${k}`);
        var k = i;
        arr2[k] = arr[i];
  k++;
    }
}

alert(arr2); // выведет 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

Проблема в том, что когда я пытаюсь выполнить сложение массива через reduce мне выдаёт тот же результат, что был бы при сложении одномерного массива.
Вот код:

```js
var result = arr2.reduce(function(prev, cur){ return prev + cur; });
alert(result); // выведет - 1,2,34,5,67,8,9
```

Если кто-то знает как решить это прошу Вас помощи.

Comment: Сейчас пишу код, проверяю... Но для начала, каждую итерацию проверять размер массива - очень плохо. А если вы что-то делаете с этим массивом внутри итерации? Надо размер заранее вычислять! `var size = arr.length;` и потом `for(i = 0; i < size; i++)`

Comment: @intro94, давным давно неактуально.

Comment: @Qwertiy это почему же? JS настолько плох, что оптимизация это не для него?

Comment: @intro94, нет, наоборот, js настолкьо хорош что современные движки эту оптимизацию делают сами

Comment: @intro94, js настолько хорош, что браузер сам оптимизирует обращение к длине массива. Последний относительно актуальный браузер, которые так не делал - это Опера 12. И цена этого обращения была около цены операции сложения.

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму, ты быстрее написал))

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму Хз. Лучше рук программиста и строгого компилятора ничего нет. :) Лично мне больше по душе С++. А если выбирать между JS и PHP, то PHP для меня фаворит, хоть он и не умеет работать на стороне клиента. :)

Comment: @intro94. Каждой задаче свой инструмент.  Быстрые вычисления обычно не пишут на js, ui не пишут на ассемблере а махровый тырпрайз на хаскеле.

Comment: @intro94, лучше рук программиста иногда кое что есть. Руки другого программиста, более умного, который написал интерпретатор. Вы же обычно не переписываете все популярные библиотеки для своего проекта в угоду копеечных оптимизаций. Или переписываете?)

Comment: @Qwertiy А что ты насчет теста скажешь? https://jsperf.com/array-length-in-loop

Comment: @Alex78191, https://jsperf.com/foreach-vs-loop/100 - вот. Да и по твоей ссылке особой разницы не видно.

Comment: @Alex78191 типичный бессмысленный микробенч без нагрузки который не говорит примерно ничего) Соответственно разница в пределах статпогрешности

Comment: @Qwertiy то есть с дополнительной переменной быстрее

Comment: @Alex78191 ну да, это немножко любопытно что в этом тесте получился чуть быстрее первый вариант, но разница такая небольшая что скорее всего получается за счет погрешностей метода тестирования/измерения/еще чего-то подобного. Я это имею в виду

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму вы правы, результаты переменчивы.

Comment: @Alex78191, я вижу, что результаты почти везде одинаковые. А там, где они не одинаковые, это больше похоже на погрешность. Вполне возможно, что там как-то не так затесалась сборка мусора при том, что в самом цикле делается запись в другой массив, что означает периодическое выделение памяти. А ещё там есть строчка с Safari 10.0.3, где получилось, что с переменной медленнее.

Comment: @Qwertiy согласен https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/672515/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bd%d0%b0-javascript?noredirect=1#comment978670_672515

Comment: @Mr.Edinorozhok если вы получили ответ на свой вопрос, то отметьте верный ответ, который вам помог, галочкой.

Comment: Дубликат вроде, ответы уже были на подобные вопросы. concat  или развернуть  spreed

Answer (score 11):

Исходя из [документации](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat), можно смело применять `concat` к исходному массиву (если он состоит только из чисел или только строк. если там объекты и прочие сложные штучки - то будет плохо).

Метод concat() возвращает новый массив, состоящий из массива, на котором он был вызван, соединённого с другими массивами и/или значениями, переданными в качестве аргументов.

**Синтаксис**

```
var new_array = old_array.concat(value1[, value2[, ...[, valueN]]])
```

где *valueN* - **Массивы и/или** значения, соединяемые в новый массив.

Там же показан пример

```
var num1 = [1, 2, 3],
    num2 = [4, 5, 6],
    num3 = [7, 8, 9];

var nums = num1.concat(num2, num3);
```

Однако если принять во внимание тот факт, что `num2 и num3` ни что иное, как те же вложенные массивы в вашем `arr`, то получится, что можно сделать так:

```js
var arr = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
];
var result = [].concat(arr[0],arr[1],arr[2] );
console.log(result);
```

## Далее

В *Javascript* имеется [оператор расширения](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) (**ES6**) или по другому *spread operator*. С помощью него выражение `[].concat(arr[0],arr[1],arr[2] )` можно сократить и получить:

```js
var arr = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]];
var result = [].concat(...arr);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 4):

На планкере проверил -  работает!

```js
var arr = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9]
];
var arr2 = [];
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
    arr2.push(arr[i][j]);
    //console.log(arr[i][j]);
  }
}

console.log(arr2);
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59774/discussion-on-answer-by-vlad-vetrov------).

Answer (score 3):

Нужно так reduce использовать

```js
var arr = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
];
var flattened = arr.reduce(function(a, b) {
  return a.concat(b);
});    
console.log(JSON.stringify(flattened)); //flattened равен [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: А вот это как раз медленно. Тут асимптотика квадратичная вместо линейной.

Comment: @Qwertiy Вообще-то я на вопрос отвечал, а не вычислительную сложность рассчитывал.

Answer (score 3):

## ES5

```js
var arr = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
];

var res = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], arr);

console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
```

## ES6

```js
var arr = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
];

var res = [].concat(...arr);

console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
```

Comment: в ES6 нет `var`

Comment: @AliaksandrPitkevich, попробуй докажи. Где это ты такое прочитать ухитрился?

Comment: @AliaksandrPitkevich еще как есть. И то что дефолтному валидатору вебшторма var не нравится не убирает его из языка.

Comment: @Qwertiy, @УткаУчитсяУму может быть в документации и не сказано об этом, но в хороших компаниях использование `var` с ES6 - считается говнокодом. Знаю, потому что пришел к нам в компанию один, вот такой как вы, и делал примерно так же, пришло письмо с IBM(именно на этом проекте я и он работаем), с намеком, чтобы писал нормальный код, соответствующий новому стандарту. Успехов.

Comment: @AliaksandrPitkevich, это одно из __возможных__ правил стиля оформления. На мой взгляд довольно спорное кстати. Вот в eslint есть правило запрещающее унарные плюсплюсы. Считать после этого конструкцию i++ говнокодом потому что Крокфорду не нравится? Мне кажется Вы путаете "считается говнокодом" с "не соответствует принятому на проекте стилю кодирования"

Comment: @AliaksandrPitkevich не говоря о том что конструкция стопроценто синтаксически валидна, и в соответствующей спеке var разумеется есть, поэтому утверждение "в es6 нет var" абсолютно ложно само по себе.

Comment: В общем, хоть я и пишу в основном let/const, запрет var больше похож на крокфордизм чем на реальную полезную рекомендацию имхо.

Comment: @AliaksandrPitkevich собсн `var с ES6 - считается говнокодом` != `в ES6 нет var` - раз уж на то пошло)

Answer (score 2):

```js
let arr = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
arr.flat()
```

Вернет:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Подробнее о методе `flat` на [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat).

Answer (score -1):

```
var arr = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
];
console.log(arr.join().split(","));
```

Comment: Так получится массив со строковыми представлениями, а не с числовыми