# JS - Как подсчитать количество элементов двумерного массива

Tags: javascript

Как подсчитать количество элементов двумерного массива?

```
const a = [
                [1, 2, 3],
                [4, 5, 6],
                [7, 8, 9]
            ],

console.log(a.length)
```

Выдаёт два а нужно 9

Answer (score 3):

Можно превратить двумерный массив в одномерный, например воспользовавшись любым вариантом ответа из вопроса [Как превратить двумерный масив в одномерный на javascript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/672515/191482) и уже там посмотреть длину `length`

Самый простой вариант:

```js
var arr = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 1, 1], [7, 8, 9]];
var result = [].concat(...arr);

console.log(result.length);
```

Comment: А почему таки у него выдаётся 2, а не 3 например?

Comment: @Isaev это неправда. запустив его код можно спокойно обнаружить ответ "3". Скорее всего он опечатался или недоглядел что-то

Comment: тогда уж и concat не нужен: `[...arr]` :)

Comment: @Grundy как это должно выглядеть? непонимаю

Comment: Я ж пример в комментарии выше привел как раз :-) вместо `var result = [].concat(...arr);` будет `var result = [...arr];`

Comment: А, не :-D вопрос снимается, не работает так :-D

Comment: @Grundy эка ты неумеха)

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, а мне пришлось задуматься что за странное колдовство)) Да и описаться прописью сложно, наверное недоглядел

Answer (score 2):

```js
const a = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9]
];

var length = a.reduce(function(totalLength, subarr) {
  return totalLength + subarr.length;
}, 0);

console.log(length)
```

Comment: `+=` не нужно, достаточно одного `+`

Answer (score 1):

```js
let a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

a.flat().length
```

Вернет: 9